# Кроссбраузерная стилизация radio CSS3, без изображений и без JS

Tags: html5, css3

Действительно ли таким способом можно сделать кроссбраузерно радиокнопки?

```css
*{font: 100% Arial; line-height:110%;}
input[type="radio"] { display:none; }
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span span {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span span {
    background-color: #3232fa;

}
input[type="radio"] + label:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:hover span {
    border-color: #3232fa;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r1" checked><label for="r1">
<span><span></span></span>радио 1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r2" checked><label for="r2">
<span><span></span></span>радио 2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r3" checked><label for="r3">
<span><span></span></span>радио 3</label>
```

Comment: да, нормально все будет.

Comment: а IE8 ? или будут квадратные?

Comment: Зачем вам IE8 в 2017 году?

Comment: А пользователям с ИЕ8, может подскажете как проверить? а то я не уверен что в ие сработает данная конструкция. У меня WIN10 по тому и не уверен..

Comment: Подскажите, где в 2017 году найти хотя бы одного пользователя IE8? :)

Comment: те пользователи видимо у кого WIN7 еще стоит? Вы уверены, нет таких?

Comment: У тех, у кого Win7, стоит IE11, в котором это отлично работает

Comment: Например комунальные старенькие пк, с лицензионной WIN7

Comment: Пусть включают обновления, с обновлениями установится IE11. Остальных слать лесом

Comment: Спасибо, Вам за реакцию, Андрей, но может у кого-то еще будут  варианты?

Comment: Вариантов не будет, в IE8 это не заработает, только JS, лучше шлите пользователей IE8 лесом

Comment: для IE8 - http://selectivizr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так еще больше кроссбраузерности (но возможно перебор... но не точно):

```css
* {
  font: 100% Arial;
  line-height: 110%;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span span {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
     -moz-border-radius: 7px;
          border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span span {
  background-color: #3232fa;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:hover span {
  border-color: #3232fa;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r1" checked><label for="r1">
<span><span></span></span>радио 1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r2" checked><label for="r2">
<span><span></span></span>радио 2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="r3" checked><label for="r3">
<span><span></span></span>радио 3</label>
```

Comment: А в IE8 всё равно не заработает

Comment: Explorer 8 - 268,526 пользователей (Explorer 6 - 17,443 пользователей )... не знаю)))) что бы бордеры работали в IE8 и ниже, нужно подключать специальный костыль допотопных фильтров...если интересно гуглите))

Comment: не в бордерах дело, IE8 не поддерживает `:checked`

Comment: @andreymal - https://www.liveinternet.ru/stat/ru/browsers.html - опят пустил скупую слезу... наверно это пользователи из ада заходят... а версии IE это уровни ада...

Comment: я понял, селекторы не поддерживаются IE<9